# Is there a way to use a sql profiler for nmemory (an in-memory database)

Tags: entity-framework, effort

I'm using Entity Framework with Effort that uses NMemory to test without having actual database side-effects.  Is there any way to view the sql that's being sent to the nmemory database?

**Edit:**
Thanks to @Gert_Arnold I have been looking in to DbContext.Database.Log.  Unfortunately my output looks like below.  Can anyone comment on this?  I'm assuming I'm getting these null entries instead of my sql.

```
Opened connection at 4/27/2015 11:08:22 AM -05:00
Started transaction at 4/27/2015 11:08:22 AM -05:00
<null>
-- Executing at 4/27/2015 11:08:23 AM -05:00
-- Completed in 132 ms with result: 1

<null>
-- Executing at 4/27/2015 11:08:23 AM -05:00
-- Completed in 5 ms with result: 1

Committed transaction at 4/27/2015 11:08:23 AM -05:00
Closed connection at 4/27/2015 11:08:23 AM -05:00
Disposed transaction at 4/27/2015 11:08:23 AM -05:00
Opened connection at 4/27/2015 11:08:24 AM -05:00
Started transaction at 4/27/2015 11:08:24 AM -05:00
<null>
-- Executing at 4/27/2015 11:08:24 AM -05:00
-- Completed in 8 ms with result: 1

Committed transaction at 4/27/2015 11:08:24 AM -05:00
Closed connection at 4/27/2015 11:08:24 AM -05:00
Disposed transaction at 4/27/2015 11:08:24 AM -05:00
```

Comment: [DbContext.Database.Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.log%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: @Impero, No you can't capture the sql because no sql is being generated.  It's just how either effort or nmemory do things.

Comment: @BunnyStrider Thank you. I actually read my way to the same thing after I posted my comment, but I appreciate you getting back to me. May I suggest you accept that as an answer to your own question? 

The reason I wanted to see the SQL generated, was to check what was inserted in the many-to-many relation tables (for the relations where I don't specifically add the many-to-many entities in the model). Instead of checking the SQL for this info, I found a way to directly access the NMemory database using reflection, thus getting a glimpse of the data in those relation tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept and log the commands.

```
 // Before command is sent tell EF about the new interceptor
 DbInterception.Add(new MyEFDbInterceptor());


// The interceptor class is called by , see the various interface methods
// just a couple shown here.
public class MyEFDbInterceptor: IDbCommandInterceptor   {
  public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)    {
     Debug.Writeln(command.CommandText );
     //Debug.Writeln(interceptionContext.Result ); // might be interesting use
}

 public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
{
  Debug.Writeln(command.CommandText );

}

 }
```

Comment: Looked promising.  CommandText is always null, must be Effort framework doing stuff differently.

Comment: try all the methods, check in debugger. I was seeing sql commands when i last tested.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using a testing framework called Effort  https://effort.codeplex.com/  I think they are doing something different.  I did check in the debugger, CommandText is always null in every method